# How to use button as scrollbar in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I want to use buttons as scrollbar in Tkinter.
Like there are two button on screen (up,down) and scrollbar (Y axis), we can use scrollbar to move screen up and down or when down is pressed
screen goes down and when up is pressed screen goes up.
How this can be done?

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation on the widget you want to scroll. They all have `xview` and `yview` methods that you can call programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Scrollable widgets have methods for scrolling the widget - `yview` for scrolling up and down, and `xview` for scrolling left and right. It's the very same methods called by the scrollbar. You can directly call these methods in your code.

For example, something like `the_text_widget.yview_scroll(1, "pages")` will scroll down one "page". You can use `units` to scroll down a "unit", which is one line in a text widget or listbox, and some small number of pixels in a canvas.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

def down():
    text.yview_scroll(1, "pages")
def up():
    text.yview_scroll(-1, "pages")

down_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Down", width=4, command=down)
up_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Up", width=4, command=up)
down_button.pack(side="left")
up_button.pack(side="left")

for i in range(1000):
    text.insert("end", f"Line #{i+1}\n")

root.mainloop()
```